# Django Rest Framework how to save a model with Related Field based on ID

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm kind of new to DRF. I have Record model that looks like this:

```
class Records(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, null=True)
    time_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    time_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

  ...
```

The RecordSerializer is this one:

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    now = datetime.today()
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
    time_start = serializers.DateTimeField(source='now')

    class Meta:
        model = Records
        fields = ("owner", "activity", "time_start")
```

And this is the view:

```
class StartApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Records
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
```

The POST request is sent from Backbone and it includes a field with the activity id, for example "{activity:12}". What should I do if I want the view to save the Record and set the activity to the Activity with the id of 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django REST Framework [provides a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#primarykeyrelatedfield) for exactly this use case.

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    owner = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='owner.username')
    time_start = serializers.DateTimeField(source='now')

    class Meta:
        model = Records
        fields = ("owner", "activity", "time_start")
```

This will produce output similar to what you are looking for, and it will accept the `id` of the activity when you want to update it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very useful reference. I'll accept it as soon as I get the view working. Right now I'm trying to solve another error, I posted it on this question, maybe you can give me a hand there too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030449/django-rest-framework-modelfield-requires-model-field-kwarg.

Comment: For DRF 4+, `PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` needs to have `activity = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(query_set= Activity.objects.all())` specified.

Answer (score 32):

The accepted answer **was true for DRF v2.x** but [is no longer for newer (3.x) versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27484906/2752041), as it would raise this `AssertionError`:

> AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, or set `read_only=True`.

For newer versions, just add the `queryset` argument to it:

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Activity.objects.all())
    // [...]
```