# Django REST Framework ModelField requires 'model_field' kwarg

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm kind of new to Django REST Framework. I'm getting this weird error that is probably caused by something simple, I write 'weird' cause I googled it several times and couldn't find any reference.

model:

```
class Records(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, null=True)
    time_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    time_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ...
```

serializer:

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelField):
    activity = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    now = datetime.today()
    owner = serializers.CharField(source='owner.username', read_only=True)
    time_start = serializers.DateTimeField(source='now')

    class Meta:
        model = Records
        fields = ("owner", "activity", "time_start")
```

view:

```
class StartApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Records
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Today app
    url(r'^today/$', views.TodayView.as_view(), name='today'),
    url(r'^start/$', views.StartApiView.as_view(), name='start'),
    ...
```

The POST request comes from backbone and the JSON all it has is a dict:`{"activity":"1"}`. What am I missing? The view is supposed to create a new Records object with the activity ForeignKey Field set to the activity received in the POST request and save it.

The error I get is:

```
ValueError at /times/start/
ModelField requires 'model_field' kwarg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your serializer base class is wrong. It should be **ModelSerializer** instead of ModelField.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # serializer implementation
```