# Django REST Framework relationship serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been banging my head against this issue and know I have to be missing something simple.

I'm trying to learn Django REST Framework and having issues setting the foreign keys of a new object to existing other objects when POSTing JSON to the server.

## models.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

## serializers.py

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name',)


class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('id', 'name',)


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)
    genre = GenreSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id','url', 'author', 'genre', 'title', 'isbn', 'summary',)
```

What I'm trying to is create a new book related to an *existing* `Author` and `Genre`. So, given some JSON like

```
{"title": "Title", 
 "author": {"id":1}
 "genre" : {"id":2}
 ...
}
```

I want to create a new book and have its `Genre` and `Author` set to the appropriate entities that are already in the database.

I've tried to change the `author` and `genre` fields on `BookSerializer` to `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` and scoured the docs and SO for answers, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028832/django-rest-framework-how-to-save-a-model-with-related-field-based-on-id?rq=1). I've tried to change the fields in the JSON to `"author": 1` or `"genre_id": 2`  but I can't seem to get it working. I keep getting `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: books_book.genre_id may not be NULL`.

I am using a DRF `ModelViewSet` for the views if that makes a difference.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Integrity error because it's expecting the `author instance` but you are sending the `pk` related to author. Try this

## serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)
    genre = GenreSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id','url', 'author', 'genre', 'title', 'isbn', 'summary',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author_id = self.initial_data.pop("author")
        genre_id = self.initial_data.pop("genre")
        author = Author.objects.get(id=author_id)
        genre = Genre.objects.get(id=genre_id)
        book = Book.objects.create(author=author, genre=genre, **validated_data)
        return book
```