# NOT NULL constraint failed: device_api_devicegroup.owner_id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting not null contraint failed error while posting a group. How should i fix it? I don't want to show the user in the api so i have not used it in the serializer fields. Do i have to compulsorily add it there?

Here is my model, serializer and APIView

```
class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)


class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ['id','name']


class DevicesGroupsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer

    def get_object(self, user, token):
        try:
            return BaseDevice.objects.filter(owner=user).get(token=token)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
            Returns a list of groups
        """
        reply = {}
        try:
            groups = DeviceGroup.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            reply['data'] = DeviceGroupSerializer(groups, many=True).data
        except:
            reply['data'] = []
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        create a new group
        """
        print('request.data', request.data)
        print('user', request.user)
        serializer = DeviceGroupSerializer(data=request.data)
        print('serializer', serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializers.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: What should the `owner` be set to if it is omitted from the API?

Comment: I just dont want owner to appear in the list view. For posting, it should know which user has posted because i am filtering the groups based on its owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this carefully, user is not in request.data:

```
serializer = DeviceGroupSerializer(data={
  'name':request.data['name'],
  'owner':request.user.id,
})
```

also check that the serializer allows the owner to be used

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ['id','name', 'owner']
```

Comment: i get MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/v1/device_groups
"'token'" error

Comment: request.data has request.data <QueryDict: {'name': ['Office'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['bN3jXN5o3TuVxjIJgcRCCJziLQqHB1']}>

Comment: This means that you are not sending the id and token fields from frontend, I understand that you need those two? Also, modify the code as you need. My intention was that you pay attention to where do you get the data from (request.data vs request.user)

Comment: I am checking from the browsable api .

Comment: if i send data={
  'name':request.data['name'],
  'owner':request.user,
} why do i still get error on device_api_devicegroup.owner_id? Is it because owner is a foreignkey?

Comment: try with 'owner':request.user.id, or with 'owner_id':request.user.id

Comment: added some more info about the serializer

Comment: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`. I gave read_only=True in owner field but the error still persists.

Comment: modified again, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028832/django-rest-framework-how-to-save-a-model-with-related-field-based-on-id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137253/discussion-between-pythonlover-and-jperelli).